# How to declare a global const variable and initialize it with a function in C?

Tags: c, constants, global-variables

I would like to declare a constant global variable and initialize it with a function. The problem is, I can't use my function to initialize it because a function call is not a compiler-time constant, but I also can't split the declaration and the initialization as it is a const variable.

For example, the following codes are invalid.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_function(void){
    return 42;
}

const int const_variable = my_function();//invalid: my_function() is not
                                         //a compiler-time constant

/*main() here*/
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int const_variable;
const_variable = 10;//invalid: can't modify a const-qualified type (const int)

/*main() here*/
```

I looked for some answers. I saw that some people suggested the use of pointers to modify the value of a const variable after its declaration, but this could cause severe readability, portability and debugging problems.

Is there any simple, portable way to solve my problem?

Comment: What you're trying to do is simply not valid C. Variables in the global scope (outside any functions) simply can't be initialized at run-time.

Comment: The only thing you can do with a const variable is initializing it upon declaration with a constant value like this: `const int const_variable = 10;`

Comment: Ok… Thank you for your comments! I'll try to find another way to do what I want.

Comment: Hobbes, what is the real function calculating?  Certainly not just 42.  Post the code of that function.  Perhaps there is a way to do that at compile time.

Comment: It is a SDL2 function, SDL_GetScancodeFromName(). I'll try and get the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to declare a global const variable and initialize it with a function in C?

There is no way. It is not possible.

> Is there any simple, portable way to solve my problem?

No.

You can use a macro `#define MY_FUNCTION()  (42)`.

You can write a separate program, that uses that C function (or is written in a completely different language), that *generates* C source code with that constant and that generated source code is then compiled with your project.

Or you can switch to a different programming language with more features, for example Rust, D, C++.

Comment: Not sure if the macro approach is helpful....

Answer (score 1):

Global consts don't work like that in C.

If a global scope variable needs protection against any further change, that's a sign you need to encapsulate it.

Create a protected_variable_setter and a getter. Make the setter known only to the file where the variable is initialized. Then access the variable only through the getter.